# how to selectively use a JQuery script with all browsers *other* than IE7?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, boilerplate

I have a script that I do not want to apply to IE7, the baseline browser for this site.

I have used HTML 5 boilerplate - with HTML class="ie7" therefore. I have tried

```
$('html:not(.ie7) .my-list li ')
```

but it still gets applied in IE7.

I know $browser is deprecated - is there a easier way to do what I am doing therefore?

The reason I am not using this script with ie7 is that I have a more essential script that applies a filter and this jquery animation will break that.

thanks for looking.

Comment: wild guess, but can IE access classes applied to the HTML tag?

Comment: @booby Your code doesn't work because Boilerplate doesn't apply those classes on the HTML element, but on the  BODY element. Your code should be: `$('body:not(.ie7) .my-list li')`...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: That's not the case. For example: `<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->`

Comment: @thirtydot You're right. They've changed it. Last year they were setting it on the BODY element.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: [I don't doubt it.](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

Comment: yeah they changed it so that body could have dynamic classes set by things like wordpress etc.

Comment: @DA I think that is maybe correct but I hope a definitive reply from someone on that! thanks for responses btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if !ie 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // script to run if *not* IE 7, but still IE
    </script>
<![end if]-->

<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // script to run if *not* IE
    </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

References:

- [Conditional comments, by Stu Nicholls of CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/conditional.html).
- [Conditional Comments, by PPK of quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).
- [Microsoft's article about Conditional Comments, at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I can try this way - do ALL browsers see the conditional comments then and not IE works therefore?

Comment: They all interpret conditional comments as HTML comments, which is why the `!IE 7` syntax looks a little complex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE here (on a mac), but either you're doing something wrong or IE can't access classes on `<html>` (or it can't apply selectors from `<html>`)

have you tried doing the same on `<body>`?

What does `$('html').hasClass('ie7')` give you?